# Converting a Pandas Series to a Well-Formed Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a groupby object:

```
g = dfchurn.groupby('ID')['isconfirm'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum())) 
type(g) 
Out[230]: pandas.core.series.Series
g.head(5)
Out[226]: 
ID         isconfirm
0000       0            0.985981
           1            0.014019
0064       0            0.996448
           1            0.003552
0080       0            0.997137
```

My goal is to get the top 100 ID's sorted by ratio descending (the right-most column) where isconfirm=0.
To do this, I thought about getting to a nice dataframe with well named columns so I can query the top ID's in terms of the ratio when isconfirm=0.

I tried, e.g.,

```
gdf = g.to_frame() 
gdf.unstack(level=1) 
gdf.head(5) 

           isconfirm          
isconfirm         0         1
ID                    
0000       0.985981  0.014019
0064       0.996448  0.003552

gdf.columns
Out[227]: Index([u'isconfirm'], dtype='object')
```

That didn't lead anywhere.   There must a clean and terse way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all rows where `isconfirm` is 0 using `g.loc`:

```
In [90]: g.loc[:, 0]
Out[90]: 
ID
0    0.827957
1    0.911111
2    0.944954
3    0.884956
4    0.931373
5    0.869048
6    0.941176
7    0.884615
8    0.901961
9    0.930693
Name: isconfirm, dtype: float64
```

The `0` in `[:, 0]` refers to the value in the second level of the index. 
Thus, you could find the `ID`s corresponding to the top 100 values using:

```
In [93]: g.loc[:, 0].sort_values(ascending=False).head(100)
Out[93]: 
ID
2    0.944954
6    0.941176
4    0.931373
9    0.930693
1    0.911111
8    0.901961
3    0.884956
7    0.884615
5    0.869048
0    0.827957
Name: isconfirm, dtype: float64

In [94]: g.loc[:, 0].sort_values(ascending=False).head(100).index
Out[94]: Int64Index([2, 6, 4, 9, 1, 8, 3, 7, 5, 0], dtype='int64', name='ID')
```

---

To produce the result above, I defined `g` this way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2017)

N = 1000
dfchurn = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                        'isconfirm': np.random.choice(2, p=[0.9, 0.1], size=N)})
g = dfchurn.groupby('ID')['isconfirm'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the hint in a related question:

```
gdf.unstack(level=1) 
gdf  = gdf.add_suffix('_ratio').reset_index()  # KEY STEP

gdf.columns   #  friendly columns now  
Index([u'ID', u'isconfirm', u'isconfirm_ratio'], dtype='object')

gdf[gdf['isconfirm_ratio'] > 0.999]   # e.g. a filter like this works now or a sort
```

Comment: The answer I accepted doesn't even make a dataframe - works directly with the series 'g' - so it's terser.